# How to get the FacebookUserId with graph api explorer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With this URL: `/v2.2/me?fields=id`, I can retrieve the user's id. (with the user's token of course)

But I noticed that it doesn't correspond to its FacebookUserId thanks to [this link](http://findmyfacebookid.com).

My goal is to reach the profile user through my Cordova app using this url scheme:

`fb://profile/facebookUserId`

since `fb://profile/id` does not work for every user...

What is this distinct id?

Comment: There is no way to do that. The Facebook app doesn't support app scoped user ids and that is the only thing you got

Comment: "There is no way to do that" > to redirect user to some user's profile?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant

Comment: @WizKid wow..frustrating..

Comment: Indeed, it well explained here: http://code-worrier.com/blog/changes-in-facebook-graph-api-2-dot-0/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an app-scoped User ID, you can use the following URL scheme to link to his/her profile

```
https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{app_scoped_id}/
```

where `{app_scoped_id}` is the numeric app-scoped User ID.

See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/#fields

Comment: Why using the fb:// url scheme in a cordova app in the first place? What do you want to achieve? what should "reach" mean? You should describe your problem in more detail... The fb:// link would only work if the native FB app is installed. What should happen otherwise?

Comment: To sum up, let's suppose a list of facebook profile pictures on the screen. When user clicks on one of them, it should be redirect to the corresponding user's profile, in order to be able to discover its profile. 99% of the users would have the native app installed. I tried with an inAppBrowser, but the main issue is that the user has to logged through Facebook on the browser, not very UX. If really the user hasn't the native FB app installed, I'll redirect it to the browser's version with the inApp browser. Hope it's clear ;)

Comment: That would have been useful information in the question. Then I guess it's not possible, as WizKid said. You could file a bug/enhancement report though

Comment: You think it's not possible due to a bug? Or rather that Facebook wants to avoid that? (since ids are not shareable and exclusive to a specific application)

Comment: It's not a "bug", it's just not implemented I guess. You'll have to file a bug request though to encourage FB to implement this feature. You'll receive an "official" answer then.